# Angular string parameters routing

Tags: angular, routes

I want to roting with string parameters in angular8. But I get an error in "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'." ngOnit. How can I do routing with string parameters ?

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    ..
  {
    path: 'student/:name',
    component: StudentComponent
  }
  ..
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

---

```
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {

  *name: string;
  private sub: any;
  

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    *this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.name = +params['value'];
    });
   
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Comment: remove the '+' from +params['value']

Comment: + remove (this.name = params['value']; ) but name is undefineted error.

Comment: try params['name']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have used + in params['value'] means you are converting your data into integer format from string format. So remove the + from this.name = +params['value'];

```
ngOnInit() {
    *this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.name = params['value'];
    });
```